# Swift Collection View to Table Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that's working fine linked to a detailViewController. However I also need to link it to a CustomCell class that's used in a table. I do not know how to set the datasource or delegate and I normally do this via the GUI in storyboards.

Should I have the collectionView in the customCell class?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? Currently facing the same issue

Comment: Afraid not, I ended up changing my design to avoid it.